# How to execute Linux shell variables within double quotes?

Tags: linux, shell, variables, sh

I have the following hacking-challenge, where we don't know, if there is a valid solution.

We have the following server script:

```
read s  # read user input into var s
echo "$s"

# tests if it starts with 'a-f'

echo "$s" > "/home/user/${s}.txt"
```

We only control the input "$s". Is there a possibility to send OS-commands like `uname` or do you think "no way"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any avenue for executing arbitrary commands. The script quotes `$s` every time it is referenced, so that limits what you can do.

The only serious attack vector I see is that the `echo` statement writes to a file name based on `$s`. Since you control `$s`, you can cause the script to write to some unexpected locations.

- `$s` could contain a string like `bob/important.txt`. This script would then overwrite `/home/user/bob/important.txt` if executed with sufficient permissions. Sorry, Bob!
- Or, worse, `$s` could be `bob/../../../etc/passwd`. The script would try to write to `/home/user/bob/../../../etc/passwd`. If the script is running as root... uh oh!

It's important to note that the script can only write to these places if it has the right permissions.

- You could embed unusual characters in `$s` that would cause irregular file names to be created. Un-careful scripts could be taken advantage of. For example, if `$s` were `foo -rf . bar`, then the file `/home/user/foo -rf . bar.txt` would be created.

  If someone ran `for file in /home/user; rm $file; done` they'd have a surprise on their hands. They would end up running `rm /home/user/foo -rf . bar.txt`, which is a disaster. If you take out `/home/user/foo` and `bar.txt` you're left with `rm -rf .` — everything in the current directory is deleted. Oops!

  (They should have quoted `"$file"`!)

And there are two other minor things which, while I don't know how to take advantage of them maliciously, do cause the script to behave slightly differently than intended.

- `read` allows backslashes to escape characters like space and newline. You can enter <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> to embed spaces and <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd> to have `read` parse multiple lines of input.
- `echo` accepts a couple of flags. If `$s` is `-n` or `-e` then it won't actually echo `$s`; rather, it will interpret `$s` as a command-line flag.

Answer (score 2):

Use `read -r s` or any `\` will be lost/missinterpreted by your command.

```
read -r s?"Your input: "
if [ -n "${s}" ]
 then
   # "filter" file name from command
   echo "${s##*/}" | sed 's|^ *\([[:alnum:]_]\{1,\}\)[[:blank:]].*|/home/user/\1.txt|' | read Output

   (
    # put any limitation on user here
    ulimit -t 5 1>/dev/null 2>&1

    `${read}`    
   ) > ${OutPut}
 else
   echo "Bad command" > /home/user/Error.txt
 fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure:

```
read s
$s > /home/user/"$s".txt
```

If I enter `uname`, this prints `Linux`. But beware: this is a security nightmare. What if someone enters `rm -rf $HOME`? You'd also have issues with commands containing a slash.

Comment: I agree with you on the security nightmare. But as long as the person does not have root-rights, it'll kill only the user's home-directory (the user will probably blame the programmer, though..).

Comment: The question posits that only `$s` can be controlled. I take that to mean the script is what it is, it can't be changed.